# Multiple MYSQL Inner Joins

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

Hi I am trying to create a search function but having trouble on getting it to work.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.ID, users.name

FROM users 
INNER JOIN usersSkills 
ON users.ID = usersSkills.userID 
INNER JOIN usersLanguages 

ON users.ID = usersLanguages.userID 
WHERE activated = "1" 
AND type = "GRADUATE" 

AND usersSkills.skillID IN(2) 
GROUP BY usersSkills.userID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 

AND usersLanguages.languageID IN(2) 
GROUP BY usersLanguages.userID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

But I keep getting this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY usersLanguages.userID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1' at line 14

If i remove one of the inner joins and group bys it works so not sure what it is can i use two group bys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tr this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.ID, users.name, COUNT(*)
FROM users 
INNER JOIN usersSkills ON users.ID = usersSkills.userID 
INNER JOIN usersLanguages ON users.ID = usersLanguages.userID 
WHERE activated = "1" 
      AND type = "GRADUATE" AND usersSkills.skillID = 2 
      AND usersLanguages.languageID = 2 
GROUP BY usersSkills.userID,
         usersLanguages.userID 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Removed the multiple erroneous `GROUP BY`'s and merged the query.
Also changed the `IN(x)` to `= x`

Comment: @AndréFigueira you sure you are supposed to have results with that query? are you still getting an error?

Comment: @AndréFigueira i changed my answer a bit.

Comment: Yes, but I am still getting a SQL Error with this query, I think because of HAVING COUNT(*) = 1

Comment: @AndréFigueira see the new version of my answe

Comment: Not sure of your version of mysql, but you can only reference columns from the select in your having statement

Comment: Actually prior to 5.0.2 of mysql you can't even reference columns from your select unless they are aggregate functions, or unless they are referenced by the group by clause of your statement.

Comment: @Neil That's fixed the error but the query now doesn't give me the desired result that being because the HAVING COUNT (*) is matching the number of results found in each table

Comment: The problem is that the having count is matching that each joined table matches x amount of rows so if there is only 1 having match we can't have an accurate result because there may only be two languages matched to an account and only 1 skill so we need to match 1 for skills and 2 for languages

Answer (score 6):

You have two group by clauses in the statement; that is invalid SQL . Do your first group by, then a comma, then your second group by. Your Having clauses should come after using ORs and ANDs to join them into a logical statement

```
GROUP BY usersSkills.userID, usersLanguages.userID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 
AND usersLanguages.languageID IN(2)
```

that answers your syntax error question.. (not trying to speak down here) but the structure of the query shows you don't really know what you want to do in the form of the query though... I would strongly suggest you get a SQL book or go through a sql tutorial so you understand what the statements you are trying to write actually do..

Comment: Is there any way i can still get the result i want? I am trying to match the user to languages they have set on the account and also skills they have set on the account.

Comment: I would ask that in a separate question so you can be specific about the output you want and give the person with the right answer appropriate credit.